# Вставить из буфера в скрытый input

Tags: input, javascript

Хочу сделать что бы при нажатии Ctrl+V содержимое буфера вставлялось в скрытый инпут (а потом я бюы делал то что мне нужно с этой вставленной строкой).

Я делаю как: по срабатываю хоткея делаю фокус на инпут и туда текст вставляется. Все отлично, до тех пор пока я не скрываю сам инпут, фокус не устанавливается.

Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы как инпут скрываете? display: none или из dom-дерева удаляете?

Comment: @alvoro предположу, что автор имеет в виду `<input type="hidden"/>`

Comment: @Fike Это настолько просто, что я и не подумал на этот способ)))

Comment: делал как тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527870/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard
type='hidden' тоже было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если Вам нужна именно такая реализация - "прячьте" с помощью

```
opacity: 0;
```

или

```
position: absolute; top: -1000px;
```

или

```
width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: первый и второй способ работают, третий нет.
я так понял у вас идея как еще можно такое релизовать, без пряток и т.д.?

Comment: @freekode, для работы с буфером есть кроссбраузерная либка, использующая Flash - zeroclipboard (https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard), думаю, с ее помощью можно осуществить получение содержимого буфера более элегантно